# Variable indexed by an indexed Set with Pyomo

Tags: python, variables, optimization, indexing, pyomo

im trying to figure out how to index a variable with an indexed Set:

For example:

```
model = AbstractModel()

model.J = Set() 
model.O = Set(model.J)
```

I want to define a variable indexed over both Sets. Can Someone help me? I tried the following:

```
model.eb=Param(model.J, model.O)
```

which gives

```
TypeError("Cannot index a component with an indexed set")
```

Has anyone any suggestions on how to define this variable properly?

Comment: What do you want `O` to be? A subset of `J`?

Comment: Yes, J is a Set of Jobs. Every Job has a different Amount of Operations (O)

Answer (score 4):

Pyomo doesn't support indexed Sets like that (I'm actually unaware of use cases for indexed sets in Pyomo, although they seem to be a thing in GAMS). You could approach this as follows (using `ConcreteModel` here, for illustration):

Define Sets for all unique values of jobs and operations (I assume you have some data structure which maps the operations to the jobs):

```py
import pyomo.environ as po
import itertools

model = po.ConcreteModel()

map_J_O = {'J1': ['O11', 'O12'],
           'J2': ['O21']}

unique_J = map_J_O.keys()
model.J = po.Set(initialize=unique_J)
unique_O = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map_J_O.values()))
model.O = po.Set(initialize=unique_O)
```

Then you could define a combined Set which contains all valid combinations of J and O:

```py
model.J_O = po.Set(within=model.J * model.O, 
                   initialize=[(j, o) for j in map_J_O for o in map_J_O[j]])

model.J_O.display()
# Output:
#J_O : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=3, Domain=J_O_domain, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
#    [('J1', 'O11'), ('J1', 'O12'), ('J2', 'O21')]
```

Create the parameter using the combined Set:

```
model.eb = po.Param(model.J_O)
```

This last line will throw an error the parameter is initialized using any non-valid combination of J and O. Alternatively, you can also initialize the parameter for all combinations

```
po.Param(model.J * model.O)
```

and only initialize for the valid combinations, but this might bite you later. Also, `model.J_O` might be handy also for variables and constraints, depending on your model formulation.

Comment: This is fantastic. How do you think it would look like if I had multiple keys instead of multiple values? (some of the keys should be ordered). More like triple (ordered) indexed set. E.g. dict[1,A,100 : 0.5; 2,A,101 : 0.9; 1,B,101 : 0.2], many rows